# Retrieve data from Collection object in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

I have something like this in my controller:

```
$item = item::where('id',1)->first();
```

I get a Collective object.

I want to retrieve a specific table from such item.

```
$item->only(['name]);
```

So I can give it to the view. However it won't work.

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2508: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::only()

How do I retrieve this concrete variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using `first()` method, you get an object, so you can just access it's properties:

```
$item = item::where('id',1)->first();
$name = $item->name;
```

Comment: @alexyMezenin , when I use  ->get() collection  colud not return on $item->name , that return on $item[0]->name, can you explain this please thank you

Comment: @noni, when you use first() instead of get() you will always get the root level object instead of array of object therefore $item instead of $item[0]

Comment: Thanks, Haisum I posted that in 2018 :) Laravel  5 newly arrived at that time. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for retrieving the single value

```
$name = item::where('id',1)->value('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any way that you want like as `select` or `pluck`

So if you wish to retrieve only column `name` you can try :

```
$item = item::where('id', 1)->select('name')->first();
$item->name;
```

or

```
$item = item::where('id', 1)->pluck('name')->first();
```

I hope it can help you to retrieve data for difference situation.

Thanks !